# display iterator in jsp

Tags: jsp, iterator

I have the following code:

```
@Override  
public Iterator retrieve() throws SQLException {  
    List<PasalBean> pasalObject = new ArrayList<PasalBean>();  
    try {  
        Class.forName(dbDriver); 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
        ps = con.createStatement();  
        rs = ps.executeQuery("select * from T_PASAL WHERE ID_PASAL = '" + id_pasal + "' ORDER BY ID_PASAL");  
        while (rs.next()) {  
            pasalObject.add(new  PasalBean(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4)));  
        }  
    }catch (Exception e) {  
        System.out.println("Error Data : " + e.getMessage());  
    }  
    return (Iterator) pasalObject;  
}
```

How can I display it in JSP?

Comment: That won't even compile. You can't cast `List` to `Iterator`.

Comment: thank's for your respond..  how i can make an iterator in my code above. and display it in jsp..  thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

First, this code will fail. You cannot cast a `List` to `Iterator`. Make it return a `List`.

Then, what you need in order to display it in a servlet is:

```
request.setAttribute("list", retrieve());
request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/jsp").forward();
```

And then in the JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
   ${item.somePropertyOfTheBean}
</c:forEach>
```

It would be good to place the `retrieve()` method in a separate, data-access class (DAO), and not directly in the servlet.

Comment: owh i see..   thank you for your help..,   but it's mean that i have an list result and not an iterator, isn't it?